# DVM transformation on common seperated XML input using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

we are working on little strange requirement and looking for your help. here are the problem statement.

As a request to our process, we are getting input as

```
<element1>A,B,C</element1>
```

Now we need to have a XSLT, DVM ( SOA 11g) to tansforme these values to output like

```
<output>X,Y,Z</output>
```

we need to achieve this in XSLT.

Comment: I a trying to split the comma seperated input using create-nodeset-from-delimited-string() function and later we need to convert that string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure XSLT 1.0 solution while I investigate this create-nodeset-from-delimited-string() function. It seems to be an oracle extension?

This template will take a given pText (eg. /element1/text()) and will call a named template (FUNC) with each part of your delimited string as ARG1.

You might want to edit this to your needs.

```
<xsl:template name="split">
  <xsl:param name="pText"/>
  <xsl:param name="separator" select="','" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length($pText) = 0"/>
    <xsl:when test="contains($pText, $separator)">
      <xsl:call-template name="FUNC">
        <xsl:with-param name="ARG1" select="substring-before($pText, $separator)"/>
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:call-template name="split">
        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, $separator)"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="FUNC">
        <xsl:with-param name="ARG1" select="$pText"/>
      </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```